# Syntastic: How to change file extension settings

Tags: c, vim, syntastic

I am working with a subset of C called c0. The syntax is pretty much identical, but the file extension is c0 instead of c. Is there a way to change my vimrc file to make Syntastic understand that c0 is the same as c so it will use the same linter for files ending in c0?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to set [FileType](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#FileType) for your `c0` extension:

Add this in your `.vimrc`

`au BufRead,BufNewFile *.c0 set ft=c`